# Flutter - undefined name of class parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having difficulties in this part of my code. It looks preety simple, however there is one thing I just don't understand.
This is my class, it looks rather basic:

```
class _ChangePageItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final bool isActive;
  final int pageIndex;
  final Function handlePagination;

  _ChangePageItem(this.label, this.isActive, this.pageIndex, this.handlePagination);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 35.0,
      height: 35.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 1.0,
          color: Colors.grey,
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
        ),
      ),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text('$label'),
        onPressed:
            isActive ? () => handlePagination(int.parse('${label}')) : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then I'm using this class in the same file:

```
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    _ChangePageItem(label, isActive, pageIndex, handlePagination),
    paginationsItems(), _PaginationItem(label: '>')],
);
```

This is the error that I'm getting:
[image]

Adding value doesn't help:
[image]

Comment: you can't use named parameters like in the second image. But where you create the variable 'label' in the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the constructor like this, or using your own variables:

```dart
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    _ChangePageItem('A String', true, 0, (){}),
    paginationsItems(), _PaginationItem(label: '>')],
);
```